# Create multiple builds of the same require.js module

Tags: module, requirejs, browser-feature-detection

Using require.js and r.js, lets say I have a module, "myModule.js".

The r.js [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#hasjs) state that they support integration with has.js such that

```
has: {
     feature: true
}
```

transforms something like:

```
if (has('feature')) {
     alert('feature detected!');
} else {
     alert('feature not supported')
}
```

to:

```
alert('feature detected!');
```

However, how can I go about creating two versions of the same module?  One version for those browsers that support the feature and another version for those browsers that do not support the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your entry point to your application is named `app`. You could create a module `app-has-foo` where the feature `foo` is true and `app-no-foo` where it is false. You have to use `create` so that `r.js` knows it has to create the modules. You use `override` to override those options that belong outside the `modules` option.

```
({
    baseUrl: ...,
    mainConfigFile: ...,
    dir: "out",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "app-has-foo",
            create: true,
            include: ["app"],
            override: {
                has: {
                    foo: true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: "app-no-foo",
            create: true,
            include: ["app"],
            override: {
                has: {
                    foo: false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I think that's pretty much what I need...however, I haven't been able to verify bc adding the override property to any of my module options (even if I leave it empty) causes a `Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.  Any thoughts on what could be causing that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error here. Is the error happening while running `r.js`?

Comment: Looks like the error was coming from this guy: https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-hogan-plugin.  I'll dig into that separately.  Thanks for the help!